# (retracted) Powershell: if conditions limitations?

Tags: powershell

I would like to check parameters in the form of variables, in the expression all set or all not set.
Unfortunately, it now strikes in every combination.

Is there a limitation in using "-and"/"-or" in a cascade with parentheses?

ProgrammeArray = ""
Programmverzeichnis = ""
If (   ((-not ($ProgrammeArray)) -and (-not ($Programmverzeichnis)) )  -or (($ProgrammeArray) -and ($Programmverzeichnis))   ) {Write-Host "Optionen ungültig!"}

Edit:
first contribution from me and then immediately such a nonsense...
I had overlooked when linking that I have considered only one of the two variables.
Thus, the query could not work as expected.
Wait a little too distracted before is written.
I thank / apologize to those who have answered me!

Comment: What does `$ProgrammeArray` contain, and what are you ultimately trying to achieve? As written this expression makes little sense.

Comment: What does "it now strikes in every combination" mean? Remember your boolean logic here. When both operands to `-and` are the same value the result will be that value (as a `[Boolean]`), so you could simplify that to `(-not $ProgrammeArray) -or $ProgrammeArray`. When `$value` and `-not $value` are the operands to `-or` then, of course, one or the other is `$true`, so you could really just simplify the whole condition to a constant `$true`. If your issue is that `Write-Host` is always executed, then that's why. Many of your parentheses here, by the way, are unnecessary and hinder clarity.

Comment: the Tour page for this site states that your code should be the minimum to demo the problem ... and should be complete enuf to run. _you have left out much of the prerequisites and that makes helping you with your code needlessly difficult_. **_please make your code comply with the recommendations for this site._**